# How can I pass large amount of data (100K-1MB) from Razor Server to Razor Client Page?

Tags: razor, .net-8.0

I have a Razor server app that is generating a PDF that needs to be passed to the client for printing.  I have already worked out the printing part, but need to figure out how to get the PDF from the server to the Razor Client Page.

I have looked at using URL parameters, Signal R, and Maybe Dependency Injection (Which as of yet have not figured out how to DI from Server to Client page)  There should be a fairly easy/straight forward way to accomplish this but so far I have not seen it.

Comment: Note: The client page is being shown/generated when the report is created on the server